# MailApp.sendEmail returning [object Object] from google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I had a script working with plaintext, but not having any luck with HTML formatting. with variables `email`, `SUBJECT`, and `MESSAGE` defined, I think this may work:

`MailApp.sendEmail(email, SUBJECT, {htmlBody: MESSAGE});`

The email sends as expected with the given subject, but the only information is "[object Object]" in plaintext.

I'm clearly messing up the syntax here, but I can't seem to reverse engineer how they did it [in this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/expense_report_approval).

Thanks!

Comment: -1 for extreme lack of research effort.  Just search Google for `MailApp.sendEmail`

Comment: Okay, I got it to work with `MailApp.sendEmail(email, SUBJECT, '', {htmlBody: MESSAGE});` but I don't understand why the third parameter must be blank. Checkbox goes to whomever can teach me :)

Comment: @SLaks, I researched quite a bit, read it all, jiggled parameters around and didn't understand why... which is why I posted here. Is this not the right place to not just fix problems but to learn about them?

Comment: @mjb Looks like you are making good progress, keep going. But yes, this is a Q&A site, rather than a learn how to program site. There are sites that teach JavaScript.

Comment: @eddyparkinson definitely understood and lesson learned. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var options = {};
options.name = "Some display name";
options.replyTo = "myEmail@domain.com";
options.htmlBody = "<b>An HTML message</b>";
MailApp.sendEmail("recipient@domain.com, title, "Plain text in case the receiver can't render HTML", options);
```

Personally I create an `options` Object that I pass to the `sendEmail()` method of the *MailApp* class. This way it's a bit easier to manage your extra parameters like HTML content.

However, you really should have read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail%28String,String,String,Object%29), which clearly states the multiple methods of sending an email. You want to send HTML content, so you need to use the method that takes the optional parameter. The optional parameter is an **Object** which has multiple key/value pairs that are used to further specify, well, *options* for the sent email.